# Mask headless chrome driver as a headed one?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, driver, headless

I’m able to load a webpage using a headed chrome driver but when trying to load the same page with headless chrome driver, the driver becomes stuck loading.

I’ve set the header agent to be the same on both, but it’s still not able to connect to the page.

Any suggestions?

I was thinking if there’s a method like

```
driver.capabilities[“headless”]=False
```

Or something like that?

Reproducible code:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'
chrome_path="/Users/"+pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]+"/Desktop/chromedriver"

# headless driver
chrome_options=Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={'+user_agent+'}')
driver1=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver1.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver1.get("http://www.adidas.com/")
```

Output:

```
TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.1 x86_64)
```

Comment: What version of chrome driver are you using?

Comment: I am using version 62.0.3202.94

Comment: Yes, I did `chrome_options.add_argument("headless")` and it makes a headless browser. It's able to connect to some pages but certain pages it cannot reach. While a headed driver is able to connect to all the pages I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

The **`add_argument`** is not `"headless"`, instead it's **`"--headless"`**

So our code will be :

```
chrome_options=Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Comment: I don't think it matters and I still get a timeout error.

Comment: Can you update the question with full error stack trace?